# UICollectionViewLayoutAttribute inconsistency error on seemingly identical attributes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am infrequently getting a 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' error on my custom collectionViewLayout due to mismatching UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, but as far as I can tell, these attributes should be equal.  Does Apple expect us to cache all these attributes and return the EXACT same ones?

Here are the two layoutAttributes in question.  As you can see, they are identical expect for their actual memory addresses.

```
<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x1703e1f00> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc00000000000000e> {length = 1, path = 0}); element kind: (DRSupplementaryViewKind); frame = (22 0; 61 25); alpha = nan; zIndex = 402;

<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x1703e3600> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0xc00000000000000e> {length = 1, path = 0}); element kind: (DRSupplementaryViewKind); frame = (22 0; 61 25); alpha = nan; zIndex = 402;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun fact, what's the result of "NaN == NaN"?  That's right, it's false.  So even though isEquals was being called on the two layoutAttributes, and even though they appear the same, isEquals was returning false because "Nothing is equal to Nan – not even NaN itself!!!"

This means that [myLayoutAttribute isEqual:[myLayoutAttribute copy]] is false, if one of the floating point attributes is NaN.  Yeah....

I hope this saves someone else the mind bending agony I've been facing.